# Fedora bash command error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fedora

I have an error everytime i run this command not sure what exactly i've typed wrong

```
#!/bin/bash
$ cat journal
#journal: add journal entries to the file
# $HOME/journal-data

file =$HOME/journal-data
date >> $file
echo -n "Enter name of person or group:"
read name
echo "$name" >> $file
echo >> $file
cat >> $file
echo "-------------------------------" >> $file
echo >> $file
```

the error is as follows

```
Project1.sh: line 2: journal: command not found
=/home/rbailey/journal-data: ERROR: cannot open `=/home/rbailey/journal-data' (No such    file      or directory)
Project1.sh: line 7: $file: ambiguous redirect
Enter name of person or group:bash Project1.sh
Project1.sh: line 10: $file: ambiguous redirect
Project1.sh: line 11: $file: ambiguous redirect
Project1.sh: line 12: $file: ambiguous redirect
Project1.sh: line 13: $file: ambiguous redirect
Project1.sh: line 14: $file: ambiguous redirect
[rbailey@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: `file=$HOME/journal-data` instead of `file =$HOME/journal-data`

Answer (score 2):

For your own convenience, feel free to use the [bash tag wiki resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), such as [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
In journal line 4:
file =$HOME/journal-data
     ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.
```